# Can't log into Ubuntu 14.04 and no command works!

Tags: 14.04, command-line, login, environment-variables

Any attempt to log into Ubuntu 14.04 keeps looping back into the login page again and again.
I tried `ctrl + alt + f2` it logs in but no command works.
it says the command (what ever it is, like sudo ...) is not included in the PATH environment variable, apparently  usr/bin is not, but how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Did you do something to the path variable? Can you run `echo $PATH`, `/bin/cat /etc/environment` and `/bin/cat /home/<your username>/.bashrc` and add the output as an [edit] to your question?

Comment: oh thanks, good reminder, I managed to edit $PATH the usual way and now its all OK.

Comment: So what was the issue? Please post an answer to your question, if you managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that $PATH does not contain necessary directories  like /bin , /usr/bin .
that's why no command is working so `export $PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` would fix the issue temporarily and you can log in the normal way and edit environmental variables appropriately.